# java/hibernate Exception: expecting IdClass mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am  upgrading a java project from spirng 2 & hibenate 3 TO spring 5.2.21.RELEASE and hibernate 5.6.9.Final

When I deploy on a server like tomcat or jetty I get the following error declaring a bean in the Persistence.xml file

```
Error Creating bean with name "demo.sessionFactory" defined in...

Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping
```

The bean created is:

```
<bean id="demo.sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
abstract="false" lazy-init="default" autowired="default">
<property name="hibernateProperties>
   <ref bean="demo.hibernateProperties"/>
</property>
<property name="entityInterceptor>
   <ref bean="demo.myInterceptor"/>
</property>
<property name="datasource>
   <ref bean="demo.mappingRessource"/>
</property>
</bean>
```

Sorry I can't share all the code as it belong to a company but I will explain every term used:

demo.myInterceptor is a bean that created with a class that implements org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor where onSave, onflush..are implemented

demo.mappingRessources is this bean

```
<bean id="demo.mappingResssources"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean"
parent="demo.mappingRessourceList"
<propety name="sourceList">
<list merge="true"></list>
</property>
</bean>
```

demo.mappingRessources is a list that has many files

```
<util:list id="demo.mappingRessources">
<value>file1.hbm.xml></value>
....
</util:list>
```

When I enter for example file1.hbm.xml I find the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="file1" table="table1" schema="schema1" catalog="demo" lazy="true">
<id ="fileId" type="int">
<column name="cl1"></column>
<generator class="native"></generator>
... same for all attributes of file1
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

when I check file1 it is a class that looks like this:

```
pubic class File1 implements Serizalizable {
private int fileId;
private String str1:
...

public File1(){}

//getters

//setters
}
```

regarding hibernateProperties it is this bean:

```
<bean id="demo.hibernateProperties
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
<property name="properties">
<props>
<prop key=hibernate.dialect">{demo.hibernateProperties.hibernate.dialect}}
</prop>
...same for other properties that are defined in a properties file
</bean>
```

I searched and found that I should add @IdClass but the project was working fine with spring 2 and older hibernate 3 but I am not sure where that should be done. I didn't create new classes. I am just upgrading dependencies spring & hibernate and modifying classes when needed (package change etc..)

**EDIT**:
For some hbm.xml files, inside class there is composite-id instead of id. Could that be the issue?

**EDIT1**:

1-What I have tried but didnt work:
disable metamodel population.

2-Comment all references to hbm.xml files as I saw some of them has composite-id and that may be issue according to what I found online.

Comment: For some hbm.xml files, inside (<class></class> ) there is composite-id instead of id. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I disabled metamodel population but it didn't work too
hibernate.ejb.metamodel.population=disabled